# CakePHP - model belongsTo 2 different model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm making a Photo model, is it a good practice to make it belong to multiple models such as User, Place, etc?
Place also belongs to User

So here is my fields for Photos.

```
id
owner_id
type (an enum of the different models such as users and places)
```

Here is the belongsTo in PhotoModel that I have

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'owner_id',
        'conditions' => array('Photo.type' => 'user'),
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Place' => array(
        'className' => 'place',
        'foreignKey' => 'owner_id',
        'conditions' => array('Photo.type' => 'place'),
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Or is it better to just create separate models such as UserPhoto, PlacePhoto etc?

Right now with this approach, I'm sometimes seeing dbo error when I set recursive to 2.

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: What error are you receiving. I did this with comments (where comments could belong to one of many models) and set it up the same way without receiving any errors.

Comment: The error happens when I set recursive to 2. It is trying to do select on User where Photo.type when User doesn't actually have a type field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach can work, although if you set recursive to 2, the clearest solution is to [create and/or destroy associations on the fly](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1045/Creating-and-Destroying-Associations-on-the-Fly) in such queries.

Answer (score 0):

If in future you are going to use UserPhoto and PlacePhoto model, then it will be better to create separate models for them. So that you can customize those models later on. Or otherwise if you are using those models rarely then you can particularly bind those models in to your controller's method.

```
$this->User->bindModel(array('belongsTo' => array(
'User' => array(
    'className' => 'User',
    'foreignKey' => 'owner_id',
    'conditions' => array('Photo.type' => 'user'),
    'fields' => '',
    'order' => ''
),
'Place' => array(
    'className' => 'place',
    'foreignKey' => 'owner_id',
    'conditions' => array('Photo.type' => 'place'),
    'fields' => '',
    'order' => ''
)));
```